# AWK: How to parse multi-line records with multiple fields on some lines

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm trying to work out parsing the output of a legacy tool (daemon process).

The query outputs fields A-K in this form:

```
A: (string)
B: (string)
C: (string)
D: # (#) E: # (#) F: #
G: #/# H: #
I: (timestamp)  J: (string)
K: (string)
```

There are multiple records arriving from a general query
and I'd like to parse each record of A-K fields to prepare for storage in a table
until a new app can be developed.

So far I have tried:

```
app -flag display | awk -v RS="" '{for(i=1; i<=NR;i++){print $i}}'
```

I only get the first "A" label, none of the rest

NOTE: There's a newline "\n" between each set of fields A-K.
I set RS="" from an example I googled. Maybe that should be RS="\n"?

Some of the data includes whitespace so that helps, except for the lines
that hold two labels, the label is included in the first data delimitation.

I'm stuck on how to progress through this piece. Or if my approach is even 
workable.

Comment: Are the labels (`A:` etc.) always arranged in that way, with e.g. `I:` and `J:` always on the same line?  May a string be on the form `A:` in the data?

Comment: Always arranged the same way. It's not in a form element. I mean that the form or shape of the data is as shown.

Comment: You don't, by sheer coincidence, want to run the loop from `1` to `NF` in lieu of `NR`? I'm asking because you set `RS=""`, so dealing with "multiline records".

Comment: I was following an example I googled.
There is a newline between each block of records.

Comment: Does `FPAT` help? `awk -v FPAT='[^[:space:]]+:[^:]*[[:space:]]+' -v RS= '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) print NR, $i}'`

Comment: That brought it closer. But the lines that have multiple fields wrapping to a new record.

Comment: Can you post an example of the _desired_ output? I still can't imagine what the command you are looking for should accomplish ...